# Abstract Property on __name__ not enforced

Tags: python, abstract-class, python-3.5, abc

Consider the following sample code:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod, abstractproperty

class Base(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self) -> str:
        print("abstract")

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def __name__(self) -> str:
        return "abstract"

    @abstractmethod
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "abstract"

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def __add__(self, other) -> str:
        return "abstract"


class Sub(Base):

    def foo(self):
        print("concrete")

    def __str__(self):
        return "concrete"

    def __add__(self, other) -> str:
        return "concrete"


sub = Sub()
sub.foo()
sub.__name__
print(str(sub))
```

Note that the subclass does not implement the abstract property `__name__`, and indeed when `__name__` is referenced, it prints as "abstract" from its parent:

```
>>> sub.foo()
concrete
>>> sub.__name__
'abstract'
>>> print(str(sub))
concrete
```

However, it is not because `__name__` is a dunder method, nor because of some issue with `@property` and `@abstractmethod` decorators not working well together, because if I remove the implementation of `__add__` from `Sub`, it does not let me instantiate it. (I know `__add__` is not normally a property, but I wanted to use a 'real' dunder method) The same expected behavior occurs if I remove the implementation of `__str__` and `foo`. Only `__name__` behaves this way.

What is it about `__name__` that causes this behavior? Is there some way around this, or do I need to have the parent (abstract) implementation manually raise the `TypeError` for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes have a `__name__` attribute by way of a *data descriptor* on `type`:

```
>>> Sub.__name__
'Sub'
>>> '__name__' in Sub.__dict__
False
```

It's a data descriptor because it also intercepts assignments to ensure that the value is a string. The actual values are stored in a slot on the C structure, the descriptor is a proxy for that value (so setting a new value on the class doesn't add a new entry to the `__dict__` either):

```
>>> Sub.__name__ = None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only assign string to NewName.__name__, not 'NoneType'
>>> Sub.__name__ = 'NewName'
>>> Sub.__name__
'NewName'
>>> '__name__' in Sub.__dict__
False
```

(actually accessing that descriptor without triggering it's `__get__` is not really possible as `type` itself has no `__dict__` and has itself a `__name__`).

This causes the test for the attribute when creating instances of `Sub` to succeed, the *class* has that attribute after all:

```
>>> hasattr(Sub, '__name__')
True
```

On instances of `Sub`, the `Base.__name__` implementation is then found because instance descriptor rules only consider the class and base classes, not the metatype.

Comment: @Keozon: checking, I'm pretty sure because there is also a descriptor on the type.

Comment: Interesting. I'm going to have to experiment with this. Thanks for the information!